# Showing alert messages in custom area - HTML Required

Tags: javascript, html, alert

by default html required alert message are shown at the bottom of textbox on click of submit button,

How could i show the required validation message on left side or any other side of textbox.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackeoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask a question to get help. Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use <span> tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for validation or [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/). Please check fiddle for custom validation message using jQuery.

```
var createAllErrors = function() {
    var form = $( this ),
        errorList = $( "ul.errorMessages", form );

    var showAllErrorMessages = function() {
        errorList.empty();

        // Find all invalid fields within the form.
        var invalidFields = form.find( ":invalid" ).each( function( index, node ) {

            // Find the field's corresponding label
            var label = $( "label[for=" + node.id + "] "),
                // Opera incorrectly does not fill the validationMessage property.
                message = node.validationMessage || 'Invalid value.';

            errorList
                .show()
                .append( "<li><span>" + label.html() + "</span> " + message + "</li>" );
        });
    };

    // Support Safari
    form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
        if ( this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity() ) {
            $( this ).find( ":invalid" ).first().focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $( "input[type=submit], button:not([type=button])", form )
        .on( "click", showAllErrorMessages);

    $( "input", form ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
        var type = $( this ).attr( "type" );
        if ( /date|email|month|number|search|tel|text|time|url|week/.test ( type )
          && event.keyCode == 13 ) {
            showAllErrorMessages();
        }
    });
};

$( "form" ).each( createAllErrors );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/subirbiswas500/br80v9hw/